# Pylint error: Module 'curses' has no 'endwin' member

Tags: visual-studio-code, pylint, python-curses

Having newly installed `windows-curses` (and restarted VS Code), I am attempting to write a context manager to abstract away `curses.initscr()` and `curses.endwin()`. However, in the problems pane, Pylint keeps throwing this error: `Module 'curses' has no 'endwin' member`. The file runs without a problem. Why might this be happening? Does it indicate a problem, or should I just turn it off?

Currently discovered members Pylint claims are missing:

- `endwin`
- `error`
- `napms`

Update: Adding this code:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--extension-pkg-whitelist=curses"
    ]
```

to settings.json changed nothing.

Comment: how are these methods defined in the .py file? Can it be statically analyzed?

Comment: @rioV8 I don't understand the question. Could you clarify?

Comment: go to the `windows-curses` py file and find the `endwin` method

Comment: @rioV8 All I'm finding for `windows-curses` is distribution information; I figured it would be defined under `curses`, but I can't find it there, either. I'm looking in `c:\users\<user>\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\curses\`.

Comment: can you find the `initscr` method? Then also look for the `endwin` method in the same module

Comment: @rioV8 I think I discovered the reason for its obscurity. `curses` is a C library. The Python `curses` library provides an interface thereto, and `windows-curses` ports that to Windows. Therefore, these members are probably defined in a C file somewhere, not in Python.

Comment: @rioV8 [Here](https://github.com/mirror/ncurses/blob/master/ncurses/base/lib_endwin.c) is a mirror of the `ncurses` source where `endwin()` is defined.

Comment: if you can call `endwin` from a Python script there has to be a definition of this function, statically coded or dynamic constructed

Comment: @rioV8 Where else should I look? I'm not finding it.

Answer (score 1):

`windows-curses` supplies `_curses`, so you'll want to use pass the flag `--extension-pkg-allow-list=_curses` to `pylint`.